# Backup is getting failed with following error

Tags: sql-server, backup

> Msg 3202, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Write on "\w-mum-fp\SQLBKP\Weekly-FL\Interactions_26_01_2014.bak" failed: 1130 (Not enough server storage is available to process this command.)
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Available storage is 400 GB and database backup size with compression is 50GB, still backup is failing. Kindly assist.

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: SQL server 2008 SP3

Comment: Are you compressing your backup?  That is possible in mssql 2008 (non express).  Two things I would check... if you are backing up to a FAT file system, and check this hack out... http://www.ghacks.net/2008/01/13/not-enough-server-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command/

Comment: most likely memory related within Windows SMB. see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304101

Comment: What's the size of the backup uncompressed? If it's bigger than 400 GB, that's likely your reason. If the data file is bigger than that, the initialization of the backup file might require more space than you have available.

Comment: 67 GB is the size of compressed backup , and total database size is 209 GB. Backing up these databases to the windows server dedicated for backup.

Comment: The issue is resolved , the backup of huge database require 30% more space than the compressed size. i cleared all the space on backup location then took full backup at once for all databases on instance. So huge database need huge space.

Answer (score 1):

The error message ["Not enough server storage is available to process this command"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Not+enough+server+storage+is+available+to+process+this+command%22+site%3Asupport.microsoft.com&t=ffsb&ia=web) is a Windows error message that can be extremely misleading.  The error message indicates there is not enough *RAM* available to complete the operation.

It is highly likely that Windows is very low on free memory - check the SQL Server "max server memory" setting to ensure there is a reasonable amount of memory left for the operating system.

This command shows how much memory SQL Server is configured to use:

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure 'max server memory (MB)';
```

See [What is a deterministic method for evaluating a sensible buffer pool size?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84234/what-is-a-deterministic-method-for-evaluating-a-sensible-buffer-pool-size) for details about what this value should be.

If you see this error, open [Windows Task Manager](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2013/08/09/task-manager-in-windows-server-2012-and-windows-8/) and check how much free memory Windows has.