# Why is Page Life Expectancy value sometimes exceptionally high (4,3 M)?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, memory, page-life-expectancy

My value of PAGE LIFE EXPECTANCY usually is in a range of 3000 - 10000.

But as you can see in the little data sample below, there are regular values of about 4,3 Milion. I get those values using typeperf and directly store the results in a sql server table using a System-DSN connection.

Command:

```
 typeperf -f SQL -s 1.2.3.4 -cf "C:\SQL-PerfMon\SqlCtr.cfg" -si 250 -o SQL:PerfMonLogDSN!MyServer -sc 6
```

The config file SqlCtr.cfg contains this line:

```
\MSSQL$InstanceName:Buffer Manager\Page life expectancy
```

Because the values of 4,3 Milions are so much different/higher than the others, I suspect some kind of mistake / error. Interesting is that some weeks ago this value appeared much more ofthen then these days. Meanwhile it shows up about 1 time per day. Unfortunately it completely ruins the charts in the reports I drive.

> Configuration: SQL 2008 R2 10.50.6000.34
>   20 GB phys. Mem. 18 GB allocated to SQL Server Max.
>   Memory Cached: 298 MB Available: 394 MB
>   Free: 104 MB

We are facing this issue on many of our SQL Servers.

Where does it come from?

Here is some sample data:

```
2015-10-28 10:34:26.546 7495
2015-10-28 10:25:18.084 7495
2015-10-28 10:21:08.156 4294847
2015-10-28 10:16:58.164 7126
2015-10-28 10:12:48.193 6876
2015-10-28 10:08:37.387 6625
2015-10-28 10:04:27.351 6375
2015-10-28 09:55:17.864 5825
2015-10-28 09:51:07.848 5575
2015-10-28 09:46:57.841 5325
2015-10-28 09:42:47.687 5075
2015-10-28 09:38:37.546 4824
2015-10-28 09:34:27.587 4574
2015-10-28 09:25:17.692 4025
2015-10-28 09:21:07.734 3775
2015-10-28 09:16:57.729 3525
2015-10-28 09:12:47.767 3425
2015-10-28 09:08:37.722 3425
2015-10-28 09:04:27.830 3425
2015-10-27 14:55:16.186 4955
2015-10-27 14:51:06.212 4955
2015-10-27 14:46:56.181 4955
2015-10-27 14:42:46.194 4955
2015-10-27 14:38:36.208 4955
2015-10-27 14:34:25.954 4955
2015-10-27 14:25:24.508 4955
2015-10-27 14:21:14.475 4955
2015-10-27 14:17:04.465 4955
2015-10-27 14:12:54.467 4955
2015-10-27 14:08:44.420 4955
2015-10-27 14:04:33.295 4955
2015-10-27 10:55:19.017 10290
2015-10-27 10:51:09.014 10040
2015-10-27 10:46:58.950 9790
2015-10-27 10:42:49.004 9540
2015-10-27 10:38:39.040 9289
2015-10-27 10:34:29.041 9040
2015-10-27 10:25:06.514 8477
2015-10-27 10:20:56.653 8227
2015-10-27 10:16:46.801 7976
2015-10-27 10:12:36.839 7727
2015-10-27 10:08:26.809 7476
2015-10-27 10:04:16.749 7227
2015-10-27 09:55:17.429 6688
2015-10-27 09:51:07.400 6437
2015-10-27 09:46:57.434 6187
2015-10-27 09:42:47.461 5937
2015-10-27 09:38:37.481 5687
2015-10-27 09:34:27.555 5437
2015-10-27 09:25:21.180 4891
2015-10-27 09:21:11.198 4641
2015-10-27 09:17:01.198 4391
2015-10-27 09:12:51.149 4141
2015-10-27 09:08:41.085 3891
2015-10-27 09:04:27.989 3637
2015-10-26 14:55:18.893 8633
2015-10-26 14:51:08.920 8633
2015-10-26 14:46:58.976 8633
2015-10-26 14:42:49.050 8633
2015-10-26 14:38:39.081 8633
2015-10-26 14:34:28.711 8633
2015-10-26 14:25:26.123 8633
2015-10-26 14:21:16.093 8633
2015-10-26 14:17:06.097 8633
2015-10-26 14:12:56.129 8633
2015-10-26 14:08:46.180 8633
2015-10-26 14:04:28.295 8633
2015-10-26 10:55:17.623 4294824
2015-10-26 10:51:07.663 6535
2015-10-26 10:46:57.689 6285
2015-10-26 10:42:47.731 6035
2015-10-26 10:38:37.762 5785
2015-10-26 10:34:27.772 5535
2015-10-26 10:25:33.617 5001
2015-10-26 10:21:23.626 4751
2015-10-26 10:17:13.650 4500
2015-10-26 10:13:03.620 4250
2015-10-26 10:08:53.618 4001
2015-10-26 10:04:28.832 3736
2015-10-23 14:55:32.920 10904
2015-10-23 14:51:19.735 10904
2015-10-23 14:47:06.752 10904
2015-10-23 14:42:53.544 10904
2015-10-23 14:38:40.113 10904
2015-10-23 14:34:27.011 10904
2015-10-23 14:26:25.955 10904
2015-10-23 14:22:12.531 10904
2015-10-23 14:17:58.824 4294748
2015-10-23 14:13:45.077 10431
2015-10-23 14:09:32.494 10179
2015-10-23 14:04:39.421 9885
2015-10-23 10:55:07.504 7099
2015-10-23 10:50:57.536 6917
2015-10-23 10:46:47.350 6917
2015-10-23 10:42:37.379 6917
2015-10-23 10:38:27.013 6917
2015-10-23 10:34:16.997 6917
2015-10-23 10:25:09.026 6917
2015-10-23 10:20:59.073 6917
2015-10-23 10:16:49.108 6917
2015-10-23 10:12:38.812 6917
2015-10-23 10:08:28.627 6917
2015-10-23 10:04:18.376 6917
2015-10-23 09:55:04.379 6917
2015-10-23 09:50:54.470 6917
2015-10-23 09:46:44.511 6917
2015-10-23 09:42:34.528 6917
2015-10-23 09:38:24.615 6917
2015-10-23 09:34:14.646 6917
2015-10-23 09:25:12.689 6917
2015-10-23 09:21:02.702 6917
2015-10-23 09:16:52.699 6917
2015-10-23 09:12:42.686 6917
2015-10-23 09:08:32.597 6917
2015-10-23 09:04:19.717 6917
2015-10-22 14:55:05.072 10348
2015-10-22 14:50:55.111 10348
2015-10-22 14:46:45.155 10348
2015-10-22 14:42:35.246 10348
2015-10-22 14:38:25.244 10348
2015-10-22 14:34:15.240 10348
2015-10-22 14:25:07.089 10957
2015-10-22 14:20:57.067 10957
2015-10-22 14:16:47.065 10957
2015-10-22 14:12:37.005 10957
2015-10-22 14:08:26.864 10957
2015-10-22 14:04:16.857 10957
2015-10-22 10:55:06.851 8210
2015-10-22 10:50:56.893 7960
2015-10-22 10:46:46.909 7710
2015-10-22 10:42:36.909 7459
2015-10-22 10:38:26.981 7210
2015-10-22 10:34:17.024 6960
2015-10-22 10:25:07.443 6411
2015-10-22 10:20:57.149 6160
2015-10-22 10:16:47.112 5910
2015-10-22 10:12:36.935 5660
2015-10-22 10:08:26.150 5409
2015-10-22 10:04:15.706 5159
2015-10-22 09:55:07.043 4609
2015-10-22 09:50:57.025 4359
2015-10-22 09:46:46.936 4110
2015-10-22 09:42:36.928 3859
2015-10-22 09:38:26.982 3609
2015-10-22 09:34:16.479 3469
2015-10-22 09:25:17.359 3469
2015-10-22 09:21:07.409 3469
2015-10-22 09:16:57.448 3469
2015-10-22 09:12:47.531 3469
2015-10-22 09:08:37.198 3469
2015-10-22 09:04:23.081 3469
2015-10-21 14:55:06.941 12878
2015-10-21 14:50:57.006 12629
2015-10-21 14:46:47.020 12378
2015-10-21 14:42:36.051 12128
2015-10-21 14:38:25.801 11877
2015-10-21 14:34:15.752 11628
2015-10-21 14:25:05.747 11078
2015-10-21 14:20:55.763 10827
2015-10-21 14:16:45.752 10577
2015-10-21 14:12:35.778 10327
2015-10-21 14:08:25.484 10077
2015-10-21 14:04:15.047 9826
2015-10-21 10:55:06.086 6852
2015-10-21 10:50:56.061 6852
2015-10-21 10:46:46.092 6852
2015-10-21 10:42:36.096 6852
2015-10-21 10:38:26.061 6852
2015-10-21 10:34:15.840 6852
2015-10-21 10:25:09.061 6852
2015-10-21 10:20:59.087 4294873
2015-10-21 10:16:49.139 8688
2015-10-21 10:12:39.011 8688
2015-10-21 10:08:28.894 8688
2015-10-21 10:04:18.417 8688
2015-10-21 09:55:05.861 8688
2015-10-21 09:50:55.851 8688
2015-10-21 09:46:45.933 8688
2015-10-21 09:42:36.036 8688
2015-10-21 09:38:26.126 8688
2015-10-21 09:34:16.183 8688
2015-10-21 09:25:26.263 8688
2015-10-21 09:21:16.264 8688
2015-10-21 09:17:06.277 8688
2015-10-21 09:12:56.335 8688
2015-10-21 09:08:46.345 8688
2015-10-21 09:04:18.661 8688
2015-10-20 14:55:04.477 17227
2015-10-20 14:50:54.512 16977
2015-10-20 14:46:44.465 16727
2015-10-20 14:42:34.480 16477
2015-10-20 14:38:24.394 16227
2015-10-20 14:34:14.428 15977
2015-10-20 14:25:34.931 15458
2015-10-20 14:21:24.875 15207
2015-10-20 14:17:14.887 14957
2015-10-20 14:13:04.880 14708
2015-10-20 14:08:54.776 14458
2015-10-20 14:04:17.361 14180
2015-10-20 10:55:12.605 11606
2015-10-20 10:51:02.650 11606
2015-10-20 10:46:52.660 11606
2015-10-20 10:42:42.006 11606
2015-10-20 10:38:31.379 11606
2015-10-20 10:34:18.072 11606
2015-10-20 10:25:09.793 11606
2015-10-20 10:20:59.814 11606
2015-10-20 10:16:49.887 11606
2015-10-20 10:12:39.874 11606
2015-10-20 10:08:29.439 11606
2015-10-20 10:04:17.206 13415
2015-10-20 09:55:12.456 13415
2015-10-20 09:51:02.498 13415
2015-10-20 09:46:52.511 13415
2015-10-20 09:42:42.121 13415
2015-10-20 09:38:29.523 13415
2015-10-20 09:34:18.576 13415
2015-10-20 09:25:21.698 13415
2015-10-20 09:21:11.670 13415
2015-10-20 09:17:01.679 13415
2015-10-20 09:12:51.733 13415
2015-10-20 09:08:37.383 13415
2015-10-20 09:04:20.531 13415
2015-10-19 14:55:04.482 22382
2015-10-19 14:50:54.494 22382
2015-10-19 14:46:44.563 22382
2015-10-19 14:42:34.601 22382
2015-10-19 14:38:24.648 22382
2015-10-19 14:34:14.702 22382
2015-10-19 14:25:10.733 22382
2015-10-19 14:21:00.703 22382
2015-10-19 14:16:50.750 4294846
2015-10-19 14:12:40.690 22011
2015-10-19 14:08:30.770 21761
2015-10-19 14:04:18.099 21509
2015-10-19 10:55:09.220 10158
2015-10-19 10:50:59.242 9908
2015-10-19 10:46:49.265 9657
2015-10-19 10:42:39.094 9407
2015-10-19 10:38:28.994 9157
2015-10-19 10:34:18.791 8907
2015-10-19 10:25:13.193 8361
2015-10-19 10:21:03.137 8111
2015-10-19 10:16:53.196 7861
2015-10-19 10:12:43.234 7611
2015-10-19 10:08:33.316 7361
2015-10-19 10:04:23.356 7111
2015-10-19 09:55:07.155 6554
2015-10-19 09:50:57.141 6305
2015-10-19 09:46:47.249 6055
2015-10-19 09:42:37.257 5805
2015-10-19 09:38:27.118 5555
2015-10-19 09:34:17.196 5304
2015-10-19 09:25:39.430 4785
2015-10-19 09:21:29.442 4536
2015-10-19 09:17:19.394 4287
2015-10-19 09:13:09.428 4037
2015-10-19 09:08:59.429 3786
2015-10-19 09:04:18.373 3506
2015-10-16 14:55:05.402 20201
2015-10-16 14:50:55.417 19950
2015-10-16 14:46:45.496 19701
2015-10-16 14:42:35.503 19450
2015-10-16 14:38:25.528 19200
2015-10-16 14:34:15.567 18951
2015-10-16 14:25:07.919 18403
2015-10-16 14:20:57.940 18153
2015-10-16 14:16:47.956 17903
2015-10-16 14:12:37.948 17652
2015-10-16 14:08:27.690 17402
2015-10-16 14:04:16.953 17151
2015-10-16 10:55:05.830 8163
2015-10-16 10:50:55.844 8163
2015-10-16 10:46:45.849 8163
2015-10-16 10:42:35.892 8163
2015-10-16 10:38:25.920 8163
2015-10-16 10:34:15.924 8163
2015-10-16 10:25:06.978 8163
2015-10-16 10:20:57.034 8163
2015-10-16 10:16:47.049 8163
2015-10-16 10:12:37.068 8163
2015-10-16 10:08:26.900 8163
2015-10-16 10:04:16.915 8163
2015-10-16 09:55:10.064 8163
2015-10-16 09:51:00.082 8163
2015-10-16 09:46:50.039 8163
2015-10-16 09:42:40.021 8163
2015-10-16 09:38:29.819 8163
2015-10-16 09:34:19.878 8163
2015-10-16 09:25:29.000 8163
2015-10-16 09:21:19.078 8163
2015-10-16 09:17:09.085 4294888
2015-10-16 09:12:58.755 13685
2015-10-16 09:08:48.223 13685
2015-10-16 09:04:20.853 13685
2015-10-15 14:55:06.326 17689
2015-10-15 14:50:56.434 17439
2015-10-15 14:46:46.531 17190
2015-10-15 14:42:36.540 16939
2015-10-15 14:38:26.623 16690
2015-10-15 14:34:16.672 16440
2015-10-15 14:25:07.523 15890
2015-10-15 14:20:57.570 15640
2015-10-15 14:16:47.602 15391
2015-10-15 14:12:37.575 15140
2015-10-15 14:08:26.596 14889
2015-10-15 14:04:15.427 14638
2015-10-15 10:55:10.078 9841
2015-10-15 10:51:00.103 9841
2015-10-15 10:46:50.181 9841
2015-10-15 10:42:40.190 9841
2015-10-15 10:38:30.296 9841
2015-10-15 10:34:20.400 9841
2015-10-15 10:25:10.378 9841
2015-10-15 10:21:00.487 9841
2015-10-15 10:16:50.460 9841
2015-10-15 10:12:40.504 9841
2015-10-15 10:08:29.776 9841
2015-10-15 10:04:18.347 9841
2015-10-15 09:55:05.690 14496
2015-10-15 09:50:55.727 14496
2015-10-15 09:46:45.743 14496
2015-10-15 09:42:35.774 14496
2015-10-15 09:38:25.830 14496
2015-10-15 09:34:15.642 14496
2015-10-15 09:25:10.285 14496
2015-10-15 09:21:00.292 14496
2015-10-15 09:16:50.234 14496
2015-10-15 09:12:40.157 14496
2015-10-15 09:08:30.097 14496
2015-10-15 09:04:17.514 14496
2015-10-14 14:55:24.900 12810
2015-10-14 14:51:11.812 12557
2015-10-14 14:46:58.455 12304
2015-10-14 14:42:45.369 12051
2015-10-14 14:38:32.236 11798
2015-10-14 14:34:19.527 11545
2015-10-14 14:25:29.654 11015
2015-10-14 14:21:16.369 10762
2015-10-14 14:17:03.346 10508
2015-10-14 14:12:50.457 10255
2015-10-14 14:08:38.209 10003
2015-10-14 14:04:27.595 9752
2015-10-14 10:55:06.094 11325
2015-10-14 10:50:56.202 11325
2015-10-14 10:46:46.235 11325
2015-10-14 10:42:36.310 11325
2015-10-14 10:38:26.392 11325
2015-10-14 10:34:16.434 11325
2015-10-14 10:25:12.064 11325
2015-10-14 10:21:02.121 11325
2015-10-14 10:16:52.148 11325
2015-10-14 10:12:42.158 11325
2015-10-14 10:08:32.235 11325
2015-10-14 10:04:22.081 11325
2015-10-14 09:55:08.860 10792
2015-10-14 09:50:58.521 10541
2015-10-14 09:46:48.460 10291
2015-10-14 09:42:38.519 10040
2015-10-14 09:38:28.604 9791
2015-10-14 09:34:18.656 9541
2015-10-14 09:25:20.580 9003
2015-10-14 09:21:10.680 8753
2015-10-14 09:17:00.696 8502
2015-10-14 09:12:50.703 8252
2015-10-14 09:08:40.435 8002
2015-10-14 09:04:22.085 7744
2015-10-13 14:55:06.935 17765
2015-10-13 14:50:57.002 17516
2015-10-13 14:46:47.063 17265
2015-10-13 14:42:37.105 17015
2015-10-13 14:38:27.172 16765
2015-10-13 14:34:17.237 16515
2015-10-13 14:25:08.168 15966
2015-10-13 14:20:58.217 15716
2015-10-13 14:16:48.214 15466
2015-10-13 14:12:38.276 15215
2015-10-13 14:08:28.307 14966
2015-10-13 14:04:18.178 14716
2015-10-13 11:45:12.235 7688
2015-10-13 11:41:02.170 7688
2015-10-13 11:36:52.091 7688
2015-10-13 11:32:42.022 7688
2015-10-13 11:28:32.056 7688
2015-10-13 11:24:22.114 7688
2015-10-13 10:55:06.505 7688
2015-10-13 10:50:56.519 7688
2015-10-13 10:46:46.585 7688
2015-10-13 10:42:36.646 7688
2015-10-13 10:38:26.712 7688
2015-10-13 10:34:16.728 7688
2015-10-13 10:25:09.377 7688
2015-10-13 10:20:59.436 7688
2015-10-13 10:16:49.536 7688
2015-10-13 10:12:39.605 7688
2015-10-13 10:08:29.447 7688
2015-10-13 10:04:18.972 7688
2015-10-13 09:55:04.823 10871
2015-10-13 09:50:54.916 10871
2015-10-13 09:46:44.997 10871
2015-10-13 09:42:35.084 10871
2015-10-13 09:38:25.168 10871
2015-10-13 09:34:15.206 10871
2015-10-06 09:55:23.632 17434
2015-10-06 09:51:13.662 17434
2015-10-06 09:47:03.696 17434
2015-10-06 09:42:53.773 17434
2015-10-06 09:38:43.898 17434
2015-10-06 09:34:34.036 17434
2015-10-06 09:25:23.123 17434
2015-10-06 09:21:13.146 17434
2015-10-06 09:17:03.181 17434
2015-10-06 09:12:53.207 17434
2015-10-06 09:08:43.046 17434
2015-10-06 09:04:33.082 17434
2015-10-05 14:55:17.728 7893
2015-10-05 14:51:07.750 7643
2015-10-05 14:46:57.768 7393
2015-10-05 14:42:47.794 7143
2015-10-05 14:38:37.853 6893
2015-10-05 14:34:27.856 6643
2015-10-05 14:25:22.040 6097
2015-10-05 14:21:12.050 5846
2015-10-05 14:17:02.098 5597
2015-10-05 14:12:52.120 5347
2015-10-05 14:08:41.433 5096
2015-10-05 14:04:31.314 4846
2015-10-05 10:55:19.867 6189
2015-10-05 10:51:09.934 5939
2015-10-05 10:46:59.980 5689
2015-10-05 10:42:50.054 5439
2015-10-05 10:38:40.125 5189
2015-10-05 10:34:30.188 4939
2015-10-05 10:25:18.376 4387
2015-10-05 10:21:08.383 4137
2015-10-05 10:16:58.459 3887
2015-10-05 10:12:48.509 3637
2015-10-05 10:08:38.466 3387
2015-10-05 10:04:28.156 3136
2015-10-05 09:55:17.151 2586
2015-10-05 09:51:07.179 2335
2015-10-05 09:46:57.251 2211
2015-10-05 09:42:47.237 2211
2015-10-05 09:38:37.237 2211
2015-10-05 09:34:27.277 2211
2015-10-05 09:25:31.566 2211
2015-10-05 09:21:21.609 2211
2015-10-05 09:17:11.566 2211
2015-10-05 09:13:01.616 2211
2015-10-05 09:08:51.618 2974
2015-10-05 09:04:30.137 2974
2015-10-02 14:55:09.520 11744
2015-10-02 14:50:59.593 11494
2015-10-02 14:46:49.693 11244
2015-10-02 14:42:39.759 10994
2015-10-02 14:38:29.807 10744
2015-10-02 14:34:19.800 10494
2015-10-02 14:25:21.805 9956
2015-10-02 14:21:11.858 9706
2015-10-02 14:17:01.898 9456
2015-10-02 14:12:51.962 9206
2015-10-02 14:08:42.041 8956
2015-10-02 14:04:32.116 8706
2015-10-02 10:55:19.385 4292319
2015-10-02 10:51:09.401 4292069
2015-10-02 10:46:59.467 1710
2015-10-02 10:42:49.516 1710
2015-10-02 10:38:39.564 1710
2015-10-02 10:34:29.597 1710
2015-10-02 10:25:24.445 4294965
2015-10-02 10:21:14.486 4294715
2015-10-02 10:17:04.556 4294465
2015-10-02 10:12:54.649 4294215
2015-10-02 10:08:44.365 4293965
2015-10-02 10:04:34.157 4293714
2015-10-02 09:55:17.410 4293157
2015-10-02 09:51:07.520 4292907
2015-10-02 09:46:57.617 4292658
2015-10-02 09:42:47.680 4292408
2015-10-02 09:38:37.732 4292158
2015-10-02 09:34:27.795 4293618
2015-10-02 09:25:19.285 4293069
2015-10-02 09:21:09.351 4292819
2015-10-02 09:16:59.357 4292570
2015-10-02 09:12:49.407 4292320
2015-10-02 09:08:39.486 4292069
2015-10-02 09:04:29.346 3306
2015-10-01 14:55:13.127 4292635
2015-10-01 14:51:03.170 4292385
2015-10-01 14:46:53.138 4292135
2015-10-01 14:42:43.180 2768
2015-10-01 14:38:32.903 2768
2015-10-01 14:34:22.976 2768
2015-10-01 14:25:19.281 2768
2015-10-01 14:21:09.304 2768
2015-10-01 14:16:59.339 2768
2015-10-01 14:12:48.947 4294833
2015-10-01 14:08:39.054 4294583
2015-10-01 14:04:26.497 4294330
2015-10-01 10:55:19.975 4294330
2015-10-01 10:51:10.005 4294079
2015-10-01 10:47:00.049 4293830
2015-10-01 10:42:50.074 4293579
2015-10-01 10:38:40.134 4293330
2015-10-01 10:34:30.164 4293079
2015-10-01 10:25:21.022 4292531
2015-10-01 10:21:11.046 4292281
2015-10-01 10:17:01.028 4292031
2015-10-01 10:12:51.128 4348
2015-10-01 10:08:40.921 4294790
2015-10-01 10:04:30.655 4294540
2015-10-01 09:55:23.738 4293993
2015-10-01 09:51:13.711 4293743
2015-10-01 09:47:03.761 4293493
2015-10-01 09:42:53.855 4293243
2015-10-01 09:38:43.925 4292993
2015-10-01 09:34:33.919 4292743
2015-10-01 09:25:30.080 4292199
2015-10-01 09:21:20.179 3383
2015-10-01 09:17:10.270 3383
2015-10-01 09:13:00.291 3383
2015-10-01 09:08:49.735 3383
2015-10-01 09:04:33.582 3383
2015-09-30 14:55:06.509 3733
2015-09-30 14:50:56.189 3733
2015-09-30 14:46:46.265 3733
2015-09-30 14:42:36.308 3733
2015-09-30 14:38:26.308 3733
2015-09-30 14:34:16.349 3733
2015-09-30 14:25:22.433 3733
2015-09-30 14:21:12.421 3733
2015-09-30 14:17:02.378 3733
2015-09-30 14:12:52.305 3733
2015-09-30 14:08:41.707 3733
2015-09-30 14:04:31.463 3733
2015-09-30 10:55:18.704 4293550
2015-09-30 10:51:08.764 4293300
2015-09-30 10:46:58.836 4293050
2015-09-30 10:42:48.904 4292800
2015-09-30 10:38:39.008 4292549
2015-09-30 10:34:28.277 4292299
2015-09-30 10:25:22.238 5201
2015-09-30 10:21:12.311 4952
2015-09-30 10:17:02.362 4702
2015-09-30 10:12:52.503 4452
2015-09-30 10:08:42.571 4201
2015-09-30 10:04:32.570 3952
2015-09-30 09:55:17.125 3396
2015-09-30 09:51:07.200 3146
2015-09-30 09:46:57.281 2896
2015-09-30 09:42:47.304 2646
2015-09-30 09:38:37.333 2396
2015-09-30 09:34:27.364 2146
2015-09-30 09:25:39.190 1677
2015-09-30 09:21:29.267 1677
2015-09-30 09:17:19.338 1677
2015-09-30 09:13:09.364 1677
2015-09-30 09:08:59.093 1677
2015-09-30 09:04:31.733 1677
2015-09-29 14:55:19.543 4292063
2015-09-29 14:51:09.624 3389
2015-09-29 14:46:59.706 4294760
2015-09-29 14:42:49.773 4294511
2015-09-29 14:38:39.858 4294261
2015-09-29 14:34:29.941 4294011
2015-09-29 14:25:20.467 4293461
2015-09-29 14:21:10.572 4293211
2015-09-29 14:17:00.633 4292961
2015-09-29 14:12:50.629 4292711
2015-09-29 14:08:40.711 4292461
2015-09-29 14:04:30.605 4292211
2015-09-29 10:55:17.698 4184
2015-09-29 10:51:07.659 3934
2015-09-29 10:46:57.647 3684
2015-09-29 10:42:47.649 3434
2015-09-29 10:38:37.692 3184
2015-09-29 10:34:27.785 2934
2015-09-29 10:25:18.201 2873
2015-09-29 10:21:08.255 2873
2015-09-29 10:16:58.261 2873
2015-09-29 10:12:47.702 2873
2015-09-29 10:08:37.447 2873
2015-09-29 10:04:27.376 2873
2015-09-29 09:55:18.418 2873
2015-09-29 09:51:08.475 2873
2015-09-29 09:46:58.497 2873
2015-09-29 09:42:48.528 4294801
2015-09-29 09:38:38.571 4294552
2015-09-29 09:34:28.660 4294301
2015-09-29 09:25:34.539 4293767
2015-09-29 09:21:24.539 4293517
2015-09-29 09:17:14.546 4293266
2015-09-29 09:13:04.332 4293017
2015-09-29 09:08:53.959 4292767
2015-09-29 09:04:37.757 4292510
2015-09-28 14:55:16.375 15817
2015-09-28 14:51:06.460 15817
2015-09-28 14:46:56.477 15817
2015-09-28 14:42:46.505 15817
2015-09-28 14:38:36.554 15817
2015-09-28 14:34:26.595 15817
2015-09-28 14:25:20.464 15817
2015-09-28 14:21:10.483 15817
2015-09-28 14:17:00.482 15817
2015-09-28 14:12:50.510 15817
2015-09-28 14:08:40.506 15817
2015-09-28 14:04:28.567 15817
2015-09-28 10:55:02.980 5341
2015-09-28 10:50:52.977 5092
2015-09-28 10:46:43.008 4841
2015-09-28 10:42:33.065 4592
2015-09-28 10:38:23.077 4341
2015-09-28 10:34:13.137 4091
2015-09-28 10:25:17.488 3555
2015-09-28 10:21:07.501 3305
2015-09-28 10:16:57.504 3056
2015-09-28 10:12:47.171 2804
2015-09-28 10:08:37.070 2555
2015-09-28 10:04:27.159 2304
2015-09-28 09:55:20.312 1813
2015-09-28 09:51:10.311 1813
2015-09-28 09:47:00.331 1813
2015-09-28 09:42:50.313 1813
2015-09-28 09:38:40.403 1813
2015-09-28 09:34:30.400 1813
2015-09-28 09:25:27.272 4294932
2015-09-28 09:21:17.337 4294682
2015-09-28 09:17:07.509 4294432
2015-09-28 09:12:57.637 4294182
2015-09-28 09:08:47.684 4293932
2015-09-28 09:04:37.282 4293681
2015-09-25 14:55:06.362 4293735
2015-09-25 14:50:56.428 4293486
2015-09-25 14:46:46.513 4293236
2015-09-25 14:42:36.545 4292986
2015-09-25 14:38:26.558 4292736
2015-09-25 14:34:16.619 4292486
2015-09-25 14:25:19.170 10442
2015-09-25 14:21:09.242 10193
2015-09-25 14:16:59.234 9942
2015-09-25 14:12:49.001 9693
2015-09-25 14:08:39.071 9442
2015-09-25 14:04:29.119 9193
2015-09-25 09:55:21.043 5844
2015-09-25 09:51:11.085 4294960
2015-09-25 09:47:01.106 4294710
2015-09-25 09:42:51.039 4294460
2015-09-25 09:38:41.118 4294210
2015-09-25 09:34:31.177 4293960
2015-09-25 09:25:32.804 4293422
2015-09-25 09:21:22.843 4293172
2015-09-25 09:17:12.861 4292921
2015-09-25 09:13:02.340 4292671
```

Comment: Can you show the command used to calculate PLE ?

Comment: @Shanky I added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4294847 is similar 4294967295 with some digits shaved, and 4294967295  is a well known value (0xFFFFFFFF). This makes me suspect an integer underflow during a substraction in the tool you use to read the values ([typeperf](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490960.aspx)). PLE is a complex counter that apps need to properly consider the base and the time interval elapsed to compute the value, see [Counter Types](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785636(WS.10).aspx), and getting the computation wrong is not unheard of.

Try to see if the odd value is shown also in [logman](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490956.aspx) collected traces, or directly in [perfmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490957.aspx).

Comment: In addition, if you have more than one NUMA node on that server you might monitor `Buffer Node:Page Life Expectancy` as well because the `Buffer Manager\Page life expectancy` is calculated from this counter. http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/page-life-expectancy-isnt-what-you-think/

Comment: I ended up with deleting of values btw. 4290000 and 4300000.