# System Monitor and Memory in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, memory

Which performance counter (System Monitor) should I use to answer the questions:

- total amount of memory currently used by SQL Server
- total amount of memory used by a process
- total amount of memory required by SQL Server for running processers efficiently.

I think that learning about the answers to these questions is the beginning of the evaluation of memory (global).

Answer (score 4):

I like the way you are thinking. Too many people don't think about these things until they've been burned by them.

You've asked about three things. Some are more "1 answer works" kind of questions. Some are more "Lots of opinions exist.

I'll take a first stab at least. One good rule of thumb, though - don't believe what Task Manager thinks. There are a few reasons that is not so reliable. Lots of memory from different places and various versions do things a slight bit different there.

There are actually a few places to see "total amount of memory currently used by SQL Server" - In perfmon/sysmon you can see two counters - "Total Server Memory" and "Target Server Memory". Simply put, the Total Server Memory is how much SQL Server **is** using. The Target Server Memory is how much SQL Server - at that moment in time- would **like** to have based on its current load. You can find this counter Perfmon in SQLServer:Memory Manager perfmon object. If you are on a Default instance it should just be SQLServer at the parent object. If a named instance, it would be something like MSSQL$InstanceName. But Memory Manager is where you can be.

For the second question - you can see a few memory counters under the Process object - and you'll see various instances for the various processes. There are a few counters here - I'd normally stick with Private Bytes to just get a generic "how much is that process actively/actually using"

For the last question - "Total amount of memory required by SQL Server for running processes efficiently" - that is a tougher nut to crack. While mileage certainly varies, I tend to look for a few adages here when I go down this road:

1. Memory is cheaper than licenses and just about everything else. You can get storage a little wrong. You can even be a bit under on procs. Memory under allocation is a sin you'll pay for for a long time - so I tend to be a bit aggressive in memory allocation where I can. (Generally).
2. If target memory is normally much higher than total memory in the point I made above - that can be a rather clear sign (do note that SQL memory takes some time to "stabilize" after a service restart - when you first bring SQL up - target and total play a game - you'll see them each grow. Wait for some stability.
3. How is Page Life Expectancy? This counter is in the SQLServer:Buffer Manager (really you should look at Buffer Nodes in case you have multiple NUMA nodes and see what all of your PLEs are for the various memory allocations in each NUMA node). Is it constantly up and down like it can't sit still? While workload and so many variables come into play - it's better to have a PLE that tends to go up or at least say stable. If it looks like a heart monitor (with a normal or fast heart rate), it could be a sign that you are having some memory pressure.

But I don't like tuning monitors only - you also have to ask "is this impacting our customers?" what's the experience like? Are folks complaining? Are queries going longer than baseline? Front end response times waiting too much on data calls? Do some SQL Server waits based monitoring - what are you watiing for mostly? Are they counters related to memory and potentially to IO?

(Of course each of those opens a whole new rabit hole.. What comes first "insufficient memory" or "bad queries?" - so take a holistic appraoch. Look at your queries. Look at overall tuning. But those counters will at least be a good start for you.

Answer (score 2):

Emphasizing on fact which Mike outlined that your question needs more detailed answer and explanation specially the part `total memory required by SQL Server to run process efficiently`. I am adding some more details for your help

> total amount of memory currently used by SQL Server

To get total memory used by SQL Server you can use below query. It queries DMV [sys.dm_os_process_memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-process-memory-transact-sql). This DMV was not there in SQL Server 2005

```
select
(physical_memory_in_use_kb/1024)Phy_Memory_usedby_Sqlserver_MB,
(locked_page_allocations_kb/1024 )Locked_pages_used_Sqlserver_MB,
(virtual_address_space_committed_kb/1024 )Total_Memory_UsedBySQLServer_MB,
process_physical_memory_low,
process_virtual_memory_low
from sys. dm_os_process_memory
```

`Phy_Memory_usedby_Sqlserver_MB`-- Gives total Physical memory used by SQL Server in MB 
`Total_Memory_usedBy_SQLServer_MB`-- Gives total memory(RAM+Page file) used by SQL Server in MB

> total amount of memory used by a process

Well this is bit hard to calculate, there is NO one DMV or query to get the *absolute* value. Memory used by process running on sql server can be found out from DMV [sys.dm_query_memory_grants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-memory-grants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Note this will only show value if the query is running and has requested memory.

```
select
requested_memory_kb,
granted_memory_kb,
required_memory_kb,
used_memory_kb
from sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants
where session_id=xxx---the session id of query whose memory you want to track
```

The column which should be of your interest is `granted_memory_kb` because this is the amount of memory granted to query to run. Please note that a query can request more memory than what is has been granted may be due to outdated stats. The memory requested is tracked by `requested_memory_kb`.

To read more about granted/requested memory please refer to excellent blog from SQL Server query processing team. [Understanding Query Memory Grants](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlqueryprocessing/2010/02/16/understanding-sql-server-memory-grant/)

You also have DMV [sys.dm_exec_requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
select 
total_grant_kb,
total_used_grant_kb,
last_used_grant_kb
from sys.dm_dexec_requests
where session_id=xxx--session id of the process.
```

Again I would look at the column `total_grant_kb`

> total amount of memory required by SQL Server for running processers efficiently

This is a bit hard to tell and would require a baseline of SQl Server. On a normal day a SQL Server would just run fine and other day may be because of some bad code which was put into production it may start responding slow. But does that really mean memory was issue or was it code. I would just help you with few perfmon counters which can give insight into how SQl server memory is behaving and you can reach to a judgement which your fine sense.

**NOTE:** When you are trying to gauge memory pressure please run this counters for a period of 7-8 hours which MUST include period of heavy load.

SQL Server: Memory Manager-- Target Server Memory (KB)

```
SQL Server: Memory Manager--Total Server Memory (KB)

SQL Server: Memory Manager- Free Memory (KB)

SQL Server: Memory Manager--Database Cache Memory (KB)

SQLServer:Memory Manager--Memory Grants Pending

SQLServer:Buffer Manager--Free Pages

SQLServer:Buffer Manager--Free List Stall/sec

SQLServer:Buffer Manager--Page Life expectancy.
```

If the SQL Server has NUMA configuration you must look at [PLE of each NUMA node](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/page-life-expectancy-isnt-what-you-think/). Its quite possible one of the NUMA node is facing memory pressure and others are not but if you look at overall PLE counter which gives you average you can get wrong indication.

1. If total and target server memory are equal there *might* be no sign of memory pressure.
2. If there is no memory grants pending and zero free list stall/sec and PLE remains high again this is sign that SQL Server has enough RAM to process things.
3. If the there is a memory pressure you may see high free list stalls/sec PLE dropping frequently. Database free pages low, target server much greater than total server memory.

**PS:** This is not a complete guide but superficial information about how to go with SQL Server memory troubleshooting. If you are not able to reach to conclusion about memory pressure share the counter details here so that we can help you in analyzing better.

Few links for further reading

- [SQL Server Memory Troubleshooting](https://mssqlwiki.com/sqlwiki/sql-performance/troubleshooting-sql-server-memory/) By karthick PK who works at Microsoft.
- [How Much Memory Does SQl Server Need](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/how-much-memory-does-my-sql-server-actually-need/) By Jonathan Kehayias from [SQLSkills.com](https://www.sqlskills.com/)
- [Using Ring Buffer to monitor Memory Pressure](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/identifying-external-memory-pressure-with-dm_os_ring_buffers-and-ring_buffer_resource_monitor/) By Jonathan Kehayias from [SQLSkills.com](https://www.sqlskills.com/)
- [Deterministic Method of Evaluating Sensible Buffer Pool Size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84234/what-is-a-deterministic-method-for-evaluating-a-sensible-buffer-pool-size)

EDIT:

> Can I assume that:
>   total amount of memory used by a process - Memory Manager: Granted Workspace Memory
>
> total amount of memory required by SQL Server for running processers efficiently - Memory Manager: Target Server Memory
>
> total amount of memory currently used by SQL Server - Memory Manager: Total Server Memory

First of all nothing you showed above will give you correct value, I would not advise you to reach to conclusion about memory used by process by performing some subtraction. There are lot of things which go inside and is not documented. Correct way is always to look at the output of DMV's