# Amount of used cache / free cache

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, cache, buffer-pool

I need to find out how much cache is used, and if there is free cache available.

Background:

Queries on a production server take a lot of time when the server is under heavy load. I suspect that the available cache is too small to serve a high number of different queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you've set the `max server memory (mb)` and `min server memory (mb)` options via `sys.sp_configure` appropriately for your server.  See my [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84234/what-is-a-deterministic-method-for-evaluating-a-sensible-buffer-pool-size) to determine what those numbers should be.

Check Page Life Expectancy to see if your buffer pool is too small.  Depending on the size of your buffer pool, a commonly mentioned number is 300 seconds (5 minutes), but this will vary depending on your needs.  This code should work well enough:

```
DECLARE @Version NVARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @VersionINT INT;
SET @Version = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion'));
SET @VersionINT = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@Version,1 ,CHARINDEX('.',@Version)-1));
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @cmd = '';
IF @VersionINT >= 9
BEGIN
    SET @cmd = 
'SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SecondsSinceRestart INT;
DECLARE @cpu_count INT;
DECLARE @physical_memory_kb INT;
DECLARE @committed_target_kb INT;
DECLARE @committed_kb INT;

DECLARE @BootTime DATETIME;
DECLARE @output TABLE
(
    RowNum INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    , [output] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
);
INSERT INTO @output ([output])
EXEC sys.xp_cmdshell @command = ''wmic os get lastbootuptime'';

;WITH c AS (
    SELECT Year = SUBSTRING(o.output, 1, 4)
        , Month = SUBSTRING(o.output, 5, 2)
        , Day = SUBSTRING(o.output, 7, 2)
        , Hour = SUBSTRING(o.output, 9, 2)
        , Minute = SUBSTRING(o.output, 11, 2)
        , Second = SUBSTRING(o.output, 13, 2)
    FROM @output o
    WHERE o.RowNum = 2
)
SELECT @BootTime = CONVERT(DATETIME, c.Year + ''-'' + c.Month + ''-'' + c.Day + ''T'' + c.Hour + '':'' + c.Minute + '':'' + c.Second, 126)
FROM c;

SET @SecondsSinceRestart = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @BootTime, GETDATE());

';
IF @VersionINT = 11
SET @cmd = @cmd + '
SELECT @cpu_count = cpu_count
        , @physical_memory_kb = physical_memory_kb
        , @committed_target_kb = committed_target_kb
        , @committed_kb = committed_kb
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info dosi
'
ELSE
SET @cmd = @cmd + '
SELECT @cpu_count = cpu_count
        , @physical_memory_kb = physical_memory_in_bytes / 1024
        , @committed_target_kb = bpool_commit_target * 8
        , @committed_kb = bpool_committed * 8
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info dosi
';

SET @cmd = @cmd + '
;WITH c AS (
    SELECT ServerName = @@SERVERNAME
        , pc.object_name
        , pc.counter_name
        , pc.instance_name
        , pc.cntr_value
        , BootTime = @BootTime
        , SecondsSinceRestart = @SecondsSinceRestart
        , cpu_count = @cpu_count
        , physical_memory_kb = @physical_memory_kb
        , committed_target_kb = @committed_target_kb
        , committed_kb = @committed_kb
    FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters pc
    WHERE pc.object_name = ''MSSQL$'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), SERVERPROPERTY(''InstanceName'')) + '':Buffer Node                                                                                                        ''
    AND pc.counter_name = ''Page life expectancy                                                                                                            ''
    AND pc.instance_name IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT RunNum = 7 
    , c.ServerName
    , c.counter_name
    , c.object_name
    , c.instance_name
    , c.cntr_value
    , c.SecondsSinceRestart
    , c.BootTime
    , Ratio = c.cntr_value / CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,0), c.SecondsSinceRestart)
    , cpu_count
    , physical_memory_kb
    , committed_target_kb
    , committed_kb
    , ServerVersion = SERVERPROPERTY(''ProductVersion'')
FROM c;';
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cmd;
END
```

You can see what objects are occupying memory using the code shown in a recent blog post I wrote over at [SQLServerScience.com](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/performance/memory-consumption-by-object/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=dba.stackexchange.com&utm_campaign=244739).